# JavaScript Self Executing Functions - What's the Difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am very familiar with self executing functions from working with jQuery.

```
(function($) { /* do stuff */ })(jQuery);
```

Today I was reading the backbone.js source and noticed that they do this:

```
(function() { /* do stuff */ }).call(this);
```

Is this achieving the same thing? Would the following 2 lines of code do the same thing?

```
(function($) { /* do stuff */ })(jQuery);
(function($) { /* do stuff */ }).call(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first form is passing in a parameter, while the second form is setting what 'this' refers to inside the executing function. They are different.

```
(function(x){ console.log(this,x); })( jQuery );
//--> [window object]
//--> [jQuery object]

(function(x){ console.log(this,x); }).call( jQuery );
//--> [jQuery object]
//--> undefined

(function(x){ console.log(this,x); }).call( jQuery, jQuery );
//--> [jQuery object]
//--> [jQuery object]
```

*For more information, see [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).*

Here's a case where you might want to use the `call` technique:

```
v = 'oh noes!'
var o = {
  v : 42,
  f : function(){
    console.log(this.v);
    (function(){ console.log(this.v) })();
  }
};
o.f();
// --> 42
// --> 'oh noes!'
```

Without setting the value of `this` via `call()`, the self-calling function is invoked in the scope of the Global (window), not the current object.

Comment: although if it was `call(jQuery, jQuery)` it would set both.

Comment: @Phrogz In call(jQuery, jQuery) is it the second parameter that is passed to the function?

Comment: @Danny Correct; read the docs on [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more details.

Comment: @Danny: Yes. The first argument to `call` is the value to use for `this`; subsequent arguments are passed to the function. (See my answer for details.)

Answer (score 3):

In their case:

```
(function() { /* do stuff */ }).call(this);
```

...they're making sure that the function gets called with a specific value for `this` (e.g., `this` within the function will be the same as `this` outside of the function).

In your case:

```
(function($) { /* do stuff */ })(jQuery);
```

...`this` within your function will be the global object, because you've called it without doing anything that sets `this`, and so `this` defaults to the global object (`window`, on browers).

In JavaScript, `this` is set entirely by how a function is called. There are two chief ways:

1. By calling the function as part of the expression that retrieves it from an object property, e.g.

   ```
   obj.foo(); // Or `obj["foo"]();
   ```

   In that case, within the call to `foo`, `this` will refer to `obj`.
2. By calling the function via its built-in [`call`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4) or [`apply`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.3) methods:

   ```
   var obj = {name: "Fred"};
   function foo(salutation, punctuation) {
       alert(salutation + " " + this.name + punctuation);
   }
   foo.call(obj, "Hi", "!");    // alerts "Hi Fred!"
   foo.apply(obj, ["Hi", "!"]); // Also alerts "Hi Fred!"
   ```

   The only difference between `call` and `apply` is how you specify arguments to pass into the function you're calling: With `call`, you just list them as discrete arguments following the `this` value you want; with `apply`, you supply them as an array.

Answer (score 1):

The first passes jQuery as the parameter $.  The second makes jQuery the 'this' variable inside the function.

Answer (score -2):

`.call` puts the function in a closure scope.

So if you did this:

```
(function($) { /* do stuff */ }).call(jQuery);
```

`$` would be `undefined`

Comment: -1 for confusing/incorrect terminology; `call` has nothing to do with closures.